# How to enable truly anonymous posting in bbPress forums?

Tags: comments, buddypress, bbpress, comment-form, forum

I have bbpress-post-topics plugin installed so that my comments forms are replaced by a bbpress forum topic, it's working but I would like to enable anonymous posting.

[image: how do i remove the fields so users can post anonymously?]

Currently, as you can see above, the Author Name, Email, Website and Topic Title are required. I would like to adjust this so only the 'topic title' is required and if they are not logged in, their posts are attributed to a user called 'anonymous'

I can edit the PHP if required - I really thought the setting in Forums for 'Allow guest users without accounts to create topics and replies' would have achieved what I'm aiming for.

Note: This problem exists in the traditional forums too, e.g.

http://www.rugbydata.com/forums/forum/aviva-premiership/

You can see the author name/email are required fields.

How do I remove them as required fields so users can really post anonymously without creating an account?

Comment: Why did this get closed? It's totally related to Wordpress - plenty of people use bbpress on Wordpress.

Comment: It's because WPSE doesn't allow discussion of third party plugins... I have opened a new question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73443601/enable-anonymous-posting-in-bbpress-remove-name-url-and-email-fields

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When we post an *empty anonymous* reply, we get the following errors:

[image: errrors]

The part of *BBPress* that's responsible for handling this, is the `bbp_new_reply_handler()` function, in the file `/bbpress/includes/replies/functions.php`. It contains these lines that are of interest to us:

```
    // User is anonymous
    if ( bbp_is_anonymous() ) {

            // Filter anonymous data
            $anonymous_data = bbp_filter_anonymous_post_data();
```

where `bbp_filter_anonymous_post_data()` is defined in the file `/bbpress/includes/replies/functions.php`.

Here's a demo plugin that should

- allow you to post a reply with empty names and emails.
- still keep the flood checks per IP number.
- not write cookies, that will pre fill the name and the email textbox.
- give you *Anonymous* as the replier's name.

where:

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Empty Anonymous Replies in BBPress
 * Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/133420/26350
 */

add_action( 'init', array( 'WPSE_Empty_Anonymous_Replies', 'init' ) );

class WPSE_Empty_Anonymous_Replies
{
        static protected $name  = 'nobody';
        static protected $email = 'nobody@example.com';

        static public function init()
        {
            add_filter( 'bbp_filter_anonymous_post_data', 
                         array( __CLASS__, 'bbp_filter_anonymous_post_data' ),                    
                         11, 2 );
            add_filter( 'bbp_pre_anonymous_post_author_name', 
                         array( __CLASS__,  'bbp_pre_anonymous_post_author_name' ) );
            add_filter( 'bbp_pre_anonymous_post_author_email',  
                         array( __CLASS__, 'bbp_pre_anonymous_post_author_email' ) );
        }

        static public function bbp_filter_anonymous_post_data( $retval, $r )
        {
            if( self::$name === $r['bbp_anonymous_name'] 
                && self::$email === $r['bbp_anonymous_email'] )
            {   
                // reset the input to skip writing cookies 
                $retval = array();

                // trick to activate the IP flood check 
                $retval['bbp_anonymous_flood_check'] = '1';
            }       
            return $retval;
        }

        static public function bbp_pre_anonymous_post_author_name( $name )
        {
            remove_filter( current_filter(), array( __CLASS__, __FUNCTION__ ) );
            if( empty( $name ) )
                $name = self::$name;

            return $name;
        }

        static public function bbp_pre_anonymous_post_author_email( $email )
        {
            remove_filter( current_filter(), array( __CLASS__, __FUNCTION__ ) );
            if( empty( $email ) )
                $email = self::$email;

            return $email;
        }
    }
```

I hope this can point you in the right direction.

Comment: So where do we put this code, some might ask?: This is a plugin, so we can create a file like `/wp-content/plugins/empty-anonymous-replies-in-bbpress/empty-anonymous-replies-in-bbpress.php`. Then we visit the plugin section in the backend and activate it. This code should also work from the `functions.php` file in the current theme directory. I hope this helps the users, that aren't sure what to do with this code.

Comment: Excellent solution @birgire and the only working code I've found online... it's a shame this question is now closed, but I opened a new question on StackOverflow and will share your solution and credit you there, along with mentioning relevant code to hide those fields in the HTML as well. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73443601/enable-anonymous-posting-in-bbpress-remove-name-url-and-email-fields

Comment: @JesseNickles thanks, great to hear it helped, welcome to share it.

Comment: By the way @birgire, any idea how to swap out `static protected $name  = 'nobody';` for auto-generating random usernames for every session (or post)... like `$random_names_list = array("John", "Mike", "Will", "Pete", "Lucy", "Barbara");` and `$random_name = $random_names_list[array_rand($random_names_list)];` ... not sure how to get that working? Much appreciated mate.

Comment: I had a quick look but it looks Im too rusty on bbpress to be able to give a meaningful suggestion on this without installing it and work through this all over again. Sorry about that ;-)