# How do I set up real anonymous posting in bbpress?

Tags: forum

I noticed a previous answer to this question. 
I tried to create the plugin but it bugged.
Anybody has a solution ?

Thank you very much
Phil

[Previous Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131550/how-do-i-set-up-real-anonymous-posting-in-bbpress-forums)

Comment: Just fix the bugs?

Comment: @toscho I think he wants us to write a code for him.

Comment: Let's move this discussion to StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73443601/enable-anonymous-posting-in-bbpress-remove-name-url-and-email-fields